# Induced representations of representations with torsion-free image

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a profinite group, $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$ of finite index and $\rho:H\to {\rm GL}_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ a $p$-adic representation of $H$ with torsion-free image.

**Question:** Is the image of the induced representation $\text{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\rho):G\to {\rm GL}_{n\cdot [G:H]}(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ also torsion-free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

We have an almost trivial counter-example: let $\rho$ be the trivial representation of $H$, then of course the image of $\rho$ is torsion-free! However, the induced representation of the trivial representation to $G$ is the permutation representation on the set of cosets $G/H$, whose image is a non-trivial finite group and obviously contains non-trivial torsion.

But we have the following: the image of the induced representation $\mathrm{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\rho)$ contains no torsion element with order prime to $m=[G:H]$.

Comment: Thanks for your counterexample. Is the word "primitive" a typo? I think you're saying "prime to m…". Moreover, Assuming $\rho$ have infinite image, do you have a counterexample?

Comment: You are right it is a typo. I think the counterexample when the image of $\rho$ is infinite can be constructed in the same way. We can take $G$ to be the direct product of a finite group with $H$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. My understanding is the following: for simplicity, assume $[G:H]=2$ and $G/H=\{H,g_2H\}$. Then it's trivial that $\text{Ind}^{G}_{H}(\rho)(g)$ has infinite order for any $g\in H$. For $g\in G\backslash H$, we have $$ \text{Ind}^{G}_{H}(\rho)(g)= \begin{pmatrix}
0 &  \rho(gg_{2})\\
\rho(g_{2}^{-1}g) & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$ Now suppose that $ \text{Ind}^{G}_{H}(\rho)(g)  $ has finite order $ N $, then $ N $ must be even, say $ N=2N_{1} $, and

Comment: we have $$  \text{Ind}^{G}_{H}(\rho)(g)^{N}= \begin{pmatrix}
 0 &  \rho(gg_{2})\\
 \rho(g_{2}^{-1}g) & 0
\end{pmatrix}^{2N_{1}}=\begin{pmatrix}
\rho(g)^{2N_{1}}&  0\\
0& \rho(g_{2}^{-1}g^{2}g_{2})^{N_{1}}
\end{pmatrix}=I_{2n}$$ which implies that $ \rho(g)^{2N_{1}}=I_{n} $, contradicting $ \rho(g) $ has infinite order.

Comment: I explain it more clearly. Set $G=H\times \Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is an arbitrary finite group. The induced representation can be viewed as a direct sum of $|\Gamma|$ copies of $\rho$. The element $(1,\gamma)\in G$ acts on this representation by permuting the copies and has finite order. This construction doesn't depend on whether $\rho$ has a finite image.

Comment: For your understanding: notice that $g\in G\backslash H$ is NOT an element of $H$ so what you actually get is $\rho(g^{2})^{N_{1}}=1$! By the assumption on $\rho$ we must have $\rho(g^{2})=1$ and this shows that $\mathrm{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\rho)(g)$ has order 2.

Comment: You are right. I get the point now.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. I just want to ask a more stupid question:  so the torsion elements in the image of the induced representation $\text{Ind}^{G}_{H}(\rho)$ form a subgroup?

Comment: When $G$ is the direct product of $H$ with some finite group isomorphic to $G/H$ then any element with a torsion image must be trivial after projecting to $H$. But if $G$ is not a direct product, we can only show that the order of this element is equal to that of its image in $G/H$. Sadly now I am unable to provide you with a counterexample but I think this is not true in general.

Comment: I agree with that it is not true in general. But is it true when $G$ is the semidirect product of $H$ with some finite group which is isomorphic to  $G/H$?